# How to make my VueCLI webpack-simple accessible in LAN (192.168.1.73:8080)?

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am making my own VueJS project, and i built it with this command :

> vue-cli webpack-simple

Then, i create my own components, everything is working, following this, i run that command :

> npm run dev

It perfectly works, no errors, and i want to see if my project is responsive, so i went on my smartphone, and tried :

> 192.168.1.73:8080

Error:

> 192.168.1.73 doesn't allow connexion.

I already tried to add :

> 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',

Same result, inside my cmd.exe it says :

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `package.json`, change the `dev` script.

By default, it is:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
```

Which defaults to localhost, so you can use this:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot --host 0.0.0.0
```